# DVDStyler: Burninng Arabic subtitles error

Tags: linux, ubuntu, dvd, dvd-burning, dvdauthor

I have Xubuntu 14.04 64 bit, I'm trying to burn 24 season 9 on DVD to be used on a DVD player, with Arabic Subtitles. I get this error, anyone knows what it means?

> ERR:  Error 84 -- Invalid or incomplete multibyte or wide character --
>   decoding subtitle file at approx line pos 1 + char pos 72

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked someone involved with the project on sourceforge, maybe the creator, and said that dvdstyler only supports utf8, so i had to change the encoding of my subtitles for it to work